# Angular copy not working on copying array

Tags: angularjs

It seems that angular.copy() is not properly working on one of the items that I am using it on. Here's the sample code and the screenshot that follows.

```
    console.log("Copy");
    $scope.traffic_data = traffic_data;
    $scope.total_data = total_data;
    console.log($scope.traffic_data);
    console.log($scope.total_data);

    console.log("Original");
    $rootScope.original_traffic_data = angular.copy($scope.traffic_data);
    $rootScope.original_total_data = angular.copy($scope.total_data);
    console.log($rootScope.original_traffic_data);
    console.log($rootScope.original_total_data);

    console.log("Variable data");
    console.log(total_data);
    console.log("=============");
```

[image]

The problem I am facing is that the

```
$rootscope.original_total_data
```

is not copying the contents of the

```
$scope.total_data
```

as seen on the screenshot. I have highlighted the different console logs to differentiate them from one another.

The line

```
console.log($rootScope.original_total_data);
```

shows no contents even though I have used angular.copy on that variable.
What am I missing here? Please help. Thanks.
Also $rootScope is already declared in the controller and it is working for the

```
$rootScope.original_traffic_data
```

so why is it not working for

```
$rootScope.original_total_data?
```

Thanks.

Comment: var copy = Object.assign({}, original). Copy function is not provided in Angular2.

Comment: @micronyks doesn't look like Angular2

Comment: @Paul is `total_data` a valid JSON object? it doesn't look like it in the console output

Comment: @Ero. you are right ! No native copy function is avialable in Angular2 so far.

Comment: this is not angular 2 by the way. thanks for pointing that out too.

Comment: I didn't notice it.

Comment: @Ero yes it's valid. it was copied to $scope.total_data.and console.log($scope.total_data) has contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`total_data` is an array, whereas `traffic_data` is an object.

`angular.copy()` distinguishes between arrays and objects. For objects it will copy all the keys (properties). For arrays, it will only copy the array elements and not any custom properties attached to it - [see source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L909).

If you want to set properties on `total_data`, you should make it into an object instead. It does not appear to have any indexed values, so this should not be a problem, and it probably should have been an object in the first place.

Comment: ohh. ok. let me try that.

Comment: you're right. it should have been an object. thanks. Saved me a lot of time.